# How to wrap a retrofit response in JAVA?

Tags: gson, retrofit, retrofit2.6

I have to use a backend that returns me this:

```
{
    "ok": true,
    "data": [
        {
            "id": 0,
            "name": "Intempestivo"
        },
        {
            "id": 1,
            "name": "Vacaciones"
        }
}
```

But other times it returns me something like this:

```
{
    "ok": true,
    "data": [
        {
            "id": 10,
            "startDate": "2020-05-29T12:00:00.000Z",
            "endDate": "2020-05-30T12:00:00.000Z",
            "status": "En revision",
            "type": "Vacaciones"
        },
        {
            "id": 11,
            "startDate": "2020-05-29T12:00:00.000Z",
            "endDate": "2020-05-30T12:00:00.000Z",
            "status": "En revision",
            "type": "Vacaciones"
        }
    ]
}
```

How I could wrap this responses in a General Response class where the only thing that change might be the data POJO object.

```
public class GeneralResponse<T> {

    @SerializedName("data")
    private WrapperData<T> wrapperData;

    @SerializedName("ok")
    private boolean ok;

    @SerializedName("error")
    private Error error;
}
```

And the wrapper data is:

```
public class WrapperData<T> {

    private T dataResponse;

    public WrapperData(T POJOResponse) {
        this.dataResponse = POJOResponse;
    }

    public T getDataResponse() {
        return dataResponse;
    }
}
```

The retrofit interface have a method like this:

```
@GET("permission_types/")
    Call<GeneralResponse<ArrayList<PermissionType>>> getPermissionTypesWrapped();
```

But when I make the request I got the following exception:

```
com.google.gson.JsonSyntaxException: java.lang.IllegalStateException: Expected BEGIN_OBJECT but was BEGIN_ARRAY at line 'n' column 'n' path $.data
```

Comment: Why not simply change `private WrapperData<T> wrapperData;` to `private List<T> wrapperData;` and `Call<GeneralResponse<PermissionType>>`?

Comment: I think about it but the API not always returns a list into the "data" node.

Answer (score 0):

I just solve this.

I replace `private WrapperData <T> wrapperData;` to `private <T> wrapperDate;` so when I wnat to get a list I call `Call<GeneralResponse<Collection<PermissionTypes>>>`